# Ruby on Rails function not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I wrote this in my controller on a RoR app.

```
class KalendarController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @week =
    if Date.today.cweek % 2 == 0
      puts "E"
    else
      puts "O"
    end
  end
end
```

the `@week` variable should hold "E" or "N" depending on the result of `Date.today.cweek % 2 == 0` so that I can display the letter "N" or "P" in the View

which looks something like this:

```
<h1>Kalendar#show</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/kalendar/show.html.erb</p>


<p><%= @week %>
```

But this is not working. Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`puts` prints the string out the command line, but returns `nil`.  So both branches of your `if` statement were returning return `nil`, and `@week` was set to `nil`.

So remove the `puts` and your good.

```
@week =
  if Date.today.cweek % 2 == 0
    "E"
  else
    "O"
  end
```

Comment: you could do it in a single line as well with `@week = Date.today.cweek % 2 == 0 ? "E" : "O"`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need modulus--you can use the `even?` method.

```
@week = Date.today.cweek.even? ? "E" : "O"
```

Comment: `@week = Date.today.cweek.even? ? "E" : "O"`

Comment: Had a typo, sorry. Try it now.